# SQL Server Data Tools: Error loading custom DeploymentPlanModifier: Required contributor with id could not be loaded

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I need to intercept an SSDT build to modify the build script. I've followed the [MSDN Deployment Plan Modifier tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn306642(v=vs.103).aspx), but when I attempt to build the database project, I get the following error:

```
Required contributor with id 'MyDeploymentContributor.SqlRestartableScriptContributor'
could not be loaded.
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012 (Version 11.0.61219.00 Update 5) and SSDT Version 11.1.50730.0.

I signed the assembly but did not specify a password.

I've followed several solutions I've found online to no avail, including the following:

1. Updating Visual Studio and SSDT;
2. Copying MyDeploymentContributor.dll and MyDeploymentContributor.pdb to the following locations:

   1. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\Extensions`
   2. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin`
   3. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120`
   4. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120\Extensions`
3. Capturing an event log for SSDT and DacFx (following Kevin Cunnane's instructions at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5c84ab8e-b50b-4ecd-86da-866ac3bb2248/known-issue-with-ssdt-extensibility-in-current-release?forum=ssdt). Here are the results from the DacFx log:

   - Core Services: SafeDirectoryCatalog: Assembly `C:\Program Files
     (x86)\Microsoft Visual Stusio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Micrsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120\Extensions\MyDeploymentContributor.dll`
     added
   - Core Services: Extension Lookup: directory `C:\Program Files
     (x86)\Microsoft Visual Stusio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Micrsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120\Extensions` added to extension lookup path
   - Core Services: FilteringCompositionContainer: Looking up exports for
     `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Deployment.DeploymentPlanExecutor`
   - Core Services: FilteringCompositionContainer: Changed part creation policy
     to NonShared
   - Core Services: FilteringCompositionContainer: Looking up exports for
     `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Deployment.DeploymentPlanModifier`

There were no `ContributorLoader` messages. From this log, the contributor seems to be loading correctly. The SSDT log didn't contain any events that mentioned the contributor.

There are no required contributor arguments, so the `DeploymentContributor` node in my .sqlproj file looks like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DeploymentContributors>
        $(DeploymentContributors); MyDeploymentContributor.SqlRestartableScriptContributor
    </DeploymentContributors>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the export of your contributor method (OnExecute?) please also grab a sample from https://github.com/DacFxDeploymentContributors/Contributors and see if that works? The logging one is a good one to see if everything is setup correctly

Comment: My OnExecute method is copied from [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461507(v=vs.100).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461507(v=vs.100).aspx) and looks like this: [http://pastebin.com/CYYv8ZsE](http://pastebin.com/CYYv8ZsE). I tried using the contributors from the github link you provided, and got the same error (and the same DacFx log entries) as before.

Comment: Palladian, I am facing the exact same issue (in my case ,it's VS 2013). Were you able to find a solution to this issue. Also, do we need to copy MyRefKey.snk along with the dll to the extensions folder?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Ed Elliot ( https://the.agilesql.club/Blogs/Ed-Elliott/About ), I was able to resolve this issue in my case.

I followed Ed's suggestions and it worked. I created a folder like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120\Extensions\[YourContributorName]\` and copied all the contents (including DLLs) from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120` to there.

In the contributor project, I referenced the DLLs inside `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120\Extensions\[YourContributorName]\`

Once the project was built successfully, I copied the contributor .dll and .pdb files to the following location:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120\Extensions\[YourContributorName]\`

Before, I was referencing the DLLs from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin`.

Hope this would help someone.

Comment: I really love when tools like this always tell you there's something wrong and never tell you what is wrong and how can you fix it.

Comment: To add a bit to this: If you are using the DacFx nuget package (or assemblies) to programmatically publish, the assembly needs to be in a subdirectory of your current directory named `Extensions\\[YourContributorName]\`