# How to override DeploymentScriptGenerator to modify generated scripts?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I created an exe application that takes  takes in SQL contents and makes them re-rerun safe.  I would like to integrate my code/application to run during publish/generate scripts  in SQL DB projects.  Could someone please throw me some suggestions. DeploymentScriptGenerator has OnExecute method that I believe generates the final script. I would like to call my code somewhere round here, where i take the final script as an input  and modify them. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Also I implemented similar approach using DeploymentPlanModifier. It is called by sqlpackage.exe when publish script is being generated and the script is modified by embedding each command in appropriate if exists check.
I think this example will give you an idea how to do it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn306642%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Comment: scar80, I saw this approach, but in my case i was planning to reuse my existing code by executing right before the SSDT writes the final output. After researching for a while, i am planning to use DeploymentPlanExecutor instead of DeploymentPlanModifier. But, now I am facing another issue where it says the Required Contributor could not be loaded ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520446/sql-server-data-tools-error-loading-custom-deploymentplanmodifier-required-con ) . Thanks for the response