# DacFx and Custom DeploymentContributor (AgileSqlClub.DeploymentFilterContributor)

Tags: dacpac, sqlpackage, dac

I've tried at least a dozen or so ways to get the module to load and work but still get the same error:

*Error SQL0: Required contributor with id 'AgileSqlClub.DeploymentFilterContributor' could not be loaded.*

I've tried to run it with DacFax/SqlPackage 150 (x64) and 140 (Both x86 and x64).
All iterations of SqlPackage command attempted:

1. **Full Path to DLL 150 DacFx**

   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe" /a:Publish /SourceFile:C:\work\somedb.dacpac /TargetConnectionString:"Server=tcp:somedb.database.windows.net,1433;" /p:ExcludeObjectTypes="Users;Permissions;Logins;RoleMembership" /p:VerifyDeployment=False /p:AllowIncompatiblePlatform=True /p:TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings=True /p:AdditionalDeploymentContributorPaths="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin\Extensions\AgileSqlClub.SqlPackageFilter.dll" /p:AdditionalDeploymentContributors=AgileSqlClub.DeploymentFilterContributor /p:AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments="SqlPackageFilter0=IgnoreName(.PainInTheRearFunction.)"
2. **Full Path to Dir w DLL 150 DacFx**

   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe" /a:Publish /SourceFile:C:\work\somedb.dacpac /TargetConnectionString:"Server=tcp:somedb.database.windows.net,1433;" /p:ExcludeObjectTypes="Users;Permissions;Logins;RoleMembership" /p:VerifyDeployment=False /p:AllowIncompatiblePlatform=True /p:TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings=True /p:AdditionalDeploymentContributorPaths="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin\Extensions" /p:AdditionalDeploymentContributors=AgileSqlClub.DeploymentFilterContributor /p:AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments="SqlPackageFilter0=IgnoreName(.PainInTheRearFunction.)"
3. **No Path 150 DacFx**

   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe" /a:Publish /SourceFile::C:\work\somedb.dacpac /TargetConnectionString:"Server=tcp:somedb.database.windows.net,1433;" /p:ExcludeObjectTypes="Users;Permissions;Logins;RoleMembership" /p:VerifyDeployment=False /p:AllowIncompatiblePlatform=True /p:TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings=True /p:AdditionalDeploymentContributors=AgileSqlClub.DeploymentFilterContributor /p:AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments="SqlPackageFilter0=IgnoreName(.PainInTheRearFunction.)"
4. **140 DacFx x86 (Doesn't support Additional Path Argument)**

   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe" /a:Publish /SourceFile:C:\work\somedb.dacpac /TargetConnectionString:"tcp:somedb.database.windows.net,1433;" /p:ExcludeObjectTypes="Users;Permissions;Logins;RoleMembership" /p:VerifyDeployment=False /p:AllowIncompatiblePlatform=True /p:TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings=True  /p:AdditionalDeploymentContributors=AgileSqlClub.DeploymentFilterContributor /p:AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments="SqlPackageFilter0=IgnoreName(.PainInTheRearFunction.)"
5. **140 DacFx x64 (Doesn't support Additional Path Argument)**

   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe" /a:Publish /SourceFile:C:\work\somedb.dacpac /TargetConnectionString:" tcp:somedb.database.windows.net,1433;" /p:ExcludeObjectTypes="Users;Permissions;Logins;RoleMembership" /p:VerifyDeployment=False /p:AllowIncompatiblePlatform=True /p:TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings=True  /p:AdditionalDeploymentContributors=AgileSqlClub.DeploymentFilterContributor /p:AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments="SqlPackageFilter0=IgnoreName(. PainInTheRearFunction.)"

Where I've tried to put the dll and pdb file:

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin\Extensions
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin\Extensions\AgileSqlClub.DeploymentFilterContributor
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Extensions
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Extension\AgileSqlClub.DeploymentFilterContributor
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Extensions
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Extension\AgileSqlClub.DeploymentFilterContributor
- Same folder as dacpac (C:\work)

I am using the release version of the AgileSqlClub Deployment Contributor downloaded in zip format from here:

- https://github.com/GoEddie/DeploymentContributorFilterer/releases/tag/1.4.4.1
- Zip contains 2 files:
- AgileSqlClub.SqlPackageFilter.dll
- AgileSqlClub.SqlPackageFilter.pdb

I've read a dozen or so articles including:

- [SQL Server Data Tools: Error loading custom DeploymentPlanModifier: Required contributor with id could not be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520446/sql-server-data-tools-error-loading-custom-deploymentplanmodifier-required-con)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/268707/exclude-certain-schema-along-with-unnamed-constraints-in-ssdt
- https://the.agilesql.club/2015/01/howto-filter-dacpac-deployments/

I am not using SSDT just downloaded versions of DacFramework.msi (140/150)

If I remove the DeploymentFilter arguments then SqlPackage loads everything but fails at the PainInTheRearFunction I am trying to filter and Ignore on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.
Lots of those links referred to "unblocking" the dll which I originally dismissed, thinking things had moved on since versions of windows that were referenced.

I still needed to do this. Screenshot below to illustrate.
Having the AgileSqlClub.SqlPackageFilter.dll in the same folder as SqlPackage.exe was where it worked

[image: Dll Properties]